# C# get/set results in Stack Overflow

Tags: c#, indexing, stack-overflow, collectionbase

I'm getting a stack overflow from using the get/set part of my index. I've tried putting the values into a list instead in the get set but with bad results.

```
class TrackList : CollectionBase
{
    public Tracks this[int i]
    {
        get
        {
            return this[i];
        }
        set
        {
            this[i] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**Main:**

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TrackList l1 = new TrackList();
        l1[0] = new Tracks(1, "Random");
        l1[1] = new Tracks(2, "Random");
        l1[2] = new Tracks(3, "Random");
    }
}
```

**Answer:**
I was looping inside my get/set. Here is the working code:

```
class TrackList : CollectionBase
{
    public Tracks this[int i]
    {
        get
        {
            return (Tracks) List[i];
        }
        set
        {
            List[i] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**Main:**

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TrackList l1 = new TrackList();
        l1.Add(new Tracks(1, "random"));
        l1.Add(new Tracks(2, "random"));
        l1.Add(new Tracks(3, "random"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why implementing an indexer? Better use List<Tracks>

Comment: Your get/set property calls on itself. Infinitely.

Comment: Like others said, you indexer calls itself recursively to infinite. Are you sure you want to inherit from CollectionBase rather than a more specialized "finite" collection ? What's your final purpose ?

Comment: Could you please come up with a better title for your question? The current one is just a bunch of tags.

Comment: @amnezjak part of an exercise at school

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are recursively calling the property indexer an infinite number of times. I think you want this:

```
public Tracks this[int i]
{
    get
    {
        return (Tracks) List[i];
    }
    set
    {
        List[i] = value;
    }
}
```

Then, add your items:

```
TrackList l1 = new TrackList();
l1.List.Add(new Tracks(1, "Random"));
l1.List.Add(new Tracks(2, "Random"));
l1.List.Add(new Tracks(3, "Random"));
```

Then replace an item using the indexer:

```
l1[1] = new Tracks(2, "Replacement");
```

Or retrieve an item using the indexer:

```
var firstItem = l1[0];
```

Trying to use `l1[i]` where `i <= l1.Count` will produce an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, as you would expect.

Comment: collectionBase does not provide an indexer

Comment: When I put that in I get this back: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.CollectionBase'

Comment: @AntP you must use List.Insert(i, value) otherwise it will throw an exception

Comment: @Ant P When I changed List[i] = value; to List.Add(value); it worked! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Rohkin `List[i] = value` is something completely different to `List.Add(value)`. Add always adds the element at end of list *extending* the list instead changing an element in it.

Comment: Add always inserts on next available index, not the one provided by indexer. To fully implement this kind of indexer more sophisticated code is necessary

Comment: @amnezjak like i said this is for a school exercise to get us familliar with the indexer, but thanks for the input.

Comment: @Rohkin Then you didn't understand the indexer yet.

Comment: @amnezjak I don't think `Insert` is appropriate since it will not replace what exists at the specified index (unintuitive behaviour). What would be more appropriate is to use the indexer above but to first `Add` them using `l1.List.Add`.

Comment: Using `list.Add` is for sure incorrect in the indexer setter.

Comment: @Rohkin I'm just saying this code doesn't fullfil your school excercise requirements

Comment: @Ant P Thank you for the explanation, I understand how I was misusing the indexer.

Answer (score 0):

First, your stackoverflow exception is caused by calling your indexer on itself:

```
    return this[i];
```

You call your indexer which calls your indexer which then calls your indexer and so on.

Your main program should look like this:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TrackList l1 = new TrackList();
        l1.Add(new Tracks(1, "Random"));
        l1.Add(new Tracks(2, "Random"));
        l1.Add(new Tracks(3, "Random"));
    }
}
```

You can't just access indexes which not yet exist in your list.

After you added its ok to get a certain element from it:

```
Tracks t = l1[2]; // to get the third element in your list
```

**DO NOT** use `list.Add` in an indexer setter. This violates the [least astonishment principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Otherwise the only possibility is to create a list with predefined number of null elements in your constructor. But I don't recommend this.

```
TrackList l1 = new TrackList(3); // in constructor create a list of 3 null elements
```

The correct way for the whole approach is using `List<Tracks>` and you are done.

Comment: `Add` is an explicit implementation on `CollectionBase`; this won't compile unless `l1` has a compile-time type of `IList` or `TrackList` implements `IList<Tracks>` itself.

Comment: I wonder what the exercise task is behind what he has to do and why he derives from CollectionBase.

Comment: I'm presuming that it's some contrived task asking him to "implement an indexer on the following class" or something similar. I can't see any real-world value to doing this given the existence of generic collections.